# avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00 freeduino

Tags: context-free-grammar

I have a freeduino board,usb1.1. ATMega 328

I am running Windows 7 and trying to run the 'Blink' program Arduino 1.5.6 Software I have chosen Arduino duemilanove as board type My Serial port is COM23

When I try to upload a program I get the error
"avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00"
how to eliminate the error?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the driver properly installed.
Then make sure that  you have disconnected any wires that are going to pin 0 (RX)/ pin 1(TX) while you do the upload. That worked for me.